# Post-processing a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is something like this possible ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.location = "http://example.com";
        setTimeout("", 10000);
        $("#some_div_element").empty();
    })
</script>
```

I am trying to setup a page that redirects to another URL and does some post processing on the redirected page. I know that there are some Chrome/FireFox extensions that runs javascript after the page is loaded. I wanted to know if I could achieve the same result using my webserver

Comment: Why are browser extensions/plug - ins allowed to run java script after the page loads?

Comment: @cyrux you have to opt in and install them in order to allow them to do that

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about passing some params via get to the target page and then on that page do some actions according to that params ?

Comment: The target page is not owned by me. It's going to be something like Google results page

Comment: oh... then you should try something like passing script as one of params to that page. the main question is how to execute it?